# Can't create DJANGO login form, that accepts either username or email

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I am trying to create a login form in django that accepts either username or email. I made custom authentication backend and it does work. Problem is in HTML input type. The form method is POST and i did write csrf_token tag, but if i set input type to text, than when i try to login with username everything works, but when i put email in it, i get an error: CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. And if i set type to email, than i can't put username in. My django version is 4.0.6 and python version is 3.10.4

Comment: I would suggest to put code excerpts - views.py/forms.py and template containing login form (e.g. login.html).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Add this in `urls.py` file

```
path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

Add this in your `HTML template`

```
{% extends 'registration/base.html' %}
{% block title %} Login {% endblock title %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block body %}

<h4>Hello! let's get started</h4>
<h6 class="font-weight-light">Sign in to continue.</h6>

<form class="pt-3" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <div class="mt-3">
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg font-weight-medium auth-form-btn">SIGN IN</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="my-2 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label text-muted">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"> Keep me signed in </label>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="auth-link text-black">Forgot password?</a> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="text-center mt-4 font-weight-light"> 
    </div>
</form>
```